# Google Analytics Custom Metrics not showing up

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, metric

I want to push the products profit of a transaction to Google Analytics. 
With this i want to generate a report where i can see the total Product revenue and it's profit for each product that has been ordered.

i'm using this api to push custom metrics to analytics ([Measurement protocol api](https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol))

I have made several custom metrics in analytics, for example:

- Productsprofit (Scope hit, decimal)
- Productsprofit2 (Scope Product, decimal)

I've googled several times and i think i need to use the Scope Hit for this type of tracking, am i right?

I've used the api to push the metric with the right indexes to Analytics

```
$analytics->setTransactionId('test'.$orderId)
        ->setAffiliation('Testshop')
        ->setRevenue(number_format($orderTotalPrice,2,'.',''))
        ->setTax(number_format($taxTotal,2,'.',''))
        ->setShipping(number_format($shippingTotal,2,'.',''))
        ->setCouponCode('');

    foreach($orderInfo['orderDetails'] as $orderDetail) {

        // Include a product, only required fields are SKU and Name
        $productData1 = [
            'sku' => $orderDetail['model'],
            'name' => $orderDetail['name'],
            'brand' => '',
            'category' => '',
            'variant' => '',
            'price' => number_format($orderDetail['price'], 2, '.', ''),
            'quantity' => $orderDetail['aantal'],
            'coupon_code' => '',
            'position' => 0,
            'custom_metric_3'=>50.45, //<-- test data (Hit)
            'custom_metric_4'=>15.50 //<-- test data (Product)
        ];

        $analytics->addProduct($productData1);
    }
// Don't forget to set the product action, in this case to PURCHASE
    $analytics->setProductActionToPurchase();

// Finally, you must send a hit, in this case we send an Event
    $analytics->setEventCategory('Checkout')
        ->setEventAction('Purchase')
        ->sendEvent();
```

I've created a custom report and added these metric to my report. But both metrics stay empty in my report.

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong ? or what might solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to send Custom Metrics through the measurment protocoll it should look like this `cm1=`. How do you build the call?
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cm_

Comment: i'm using this api https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol . I don't think you need to add cm1= for this in this api.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP library that you are using, custom metrics and dimensions are set in a different manner depending on the scope, for Product scope you use the product array like you did, for Hit scope you use the `setCustomMetric` method. In your code this would look like:

```
$analytics->setTransactionId('test'.$orderId)
    ->setAffiliation('Testshop')
    ->setRevenue(number_format($orderTotalPrice,2,'.',''))
    ->setTax(number_format($taxTotal,2,'.',''))
    ->setShipping(number_format($shippingTotal,2,'.',''));

foreach($orderInfo['orderDetails'] as $orderDetail) {

    $productData1 = [
        'sku' => $orderDetail['model'],
        'name' => $orderDetail['name'],
        'brand' => 'the brand',
        'category' => 'test category',
        'variant' => 'variant x',
        'price' => number_format($orderDetail['price'], 2, '.', ''),
        'quantity' => $orderDetail['qty'],
        'coupon_code' => 'coupon used',
        'custom_metric_4' => 15.50,
    ];

    $analytics->addProduct($productData1);
}

$analytics->setProductActionToPurchase();

$analytics->setCustomMetric(50.45, 3);

$analytics->setEventCategory('Checkout')
    ->setEventAction('Purchase')
    ->sendEvent();
```

Notice the call to `$analytics->setCustomMetric(50.45, 3);` before sending the hit. This should send the right data, the rest is creating or looking at the right report in Google Analytics.